# Apigee Service Callout

Tags: apigee

I have a service callout in Apigee where instead of hardcoding the Url for the HTTPTargetConnection I want to use a variable for the value of the url.
Example:
http://{request.queryparam.url}
This is giving me a 404 Not Found error but if I hardcode the same value that is passed as a queryparam it works fine and calls the target service and return a response.I am not able to find any details on this in docs.Please help me out.Thanks.

Comment: Can you include your code so we can take a look?

Comment: Thanks for the answer I looked into javascript policy and used httpClient which the docs say is an alternative to service callout and solved my problem.I get the url from the query parameter and using the httpClient call that url.

This is some sample application I am just developing to get familiar with the product.Here I call one proxy from another proxy.Both are in apigee cloud and am using the free cloud version.Both the calling and the called proxy doesnt have a target backend service.

Answer (score 0):

This is potentially a bug. 
Please attach a policy of your own in the `target.xml` request part of the application which assigns the `target.url` variable with your variable of choice.  You can use assign variable or javascript or python as you wish for this policy.

EDIT:
What I answered above applies for target callouts. Not service callouts. To better understand the issue I request you to post the debug.xml in a pastebin or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I looked into javascript policy and used httpClient which the docs say is an alternative to service callout and solved my problem.I get the url from the query parameter and using the httpClient call that url.

This is some sample application I am just developing to get familiar with the product.Here I call one proxy from another proxy.Both are in apigee cloud and am using the free cloud version.Both the calling and the called proxy doesnt have a target backend service.